# How to hide (invisible) a button in windowbuilder (JFrame)?

Tags: java, eclipse, jframe, windowbuilder

I have a button in my JFrame (windowbuilder). I would like to hide this button using its properties, but I couldn't find any related property for this purpose. Just it is possible to enable/disable it, but a disable button is visible yet.

Thank you

Comment: Have you tried setVisible method of the button?

Comment: @ uoyilmaz, Thank you. It's ok. but apparently, there is no visual property in windowbuilder for this. just it's possible to do that in the code. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Every Item you add to your Gui with the WindowsBuilder can be setup separatly in the source code. If you use:

```
<objectname>.setVisible(false);
```

it should be not visible in your gui. To do that: Switch from the Desgin-Tab into the Source-Tab search for the button and add this line of code with your name of the variable.